# /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: dns

I’ve seen many people configuring /etc/resolv.conf. I read this is a file which contains the dns name servers which you configure in /etc/network/interfaces. My question is Why if I configure dns-nameservers in network configuration I have to do it again in /etc/resolv.conf.
What’s the difference?

Comment: The use of resolv.conf has changed over time, the file you mention is now created on boot, or restart of networking & many other times - ie. it's no longer an intended place to make changes if you want them to stick.  You haven't said what release (or releases) you are talking about.

Comment: I want to create a DNS name-servers master-slave with a Ubunutu18(slave) and Ubunu16(master)

Comment: You should add detail to your question (not comments), and be specific. You want to use Ubuntu Core 18 and Ubuntu Core 16 (*not standard Ubuntu yy.mm releases for example, ie. use correct release names to avoid any confusion*).  Also the difference part of your question is your releases are *systemd* based thus file is no longer static (being re-written by *networkd*).